# How to call the aggregate function in another function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I need to return t1 function data in t2 function. i tries this method but it says undefined please kindly help :) thank you!

```
function t1() {
        db.users.aggregate(
            [{
                    $group: {
                        "_id": {
                            "_id": "$_id",
                            "name": "$name",
                            "email": "$email"
                        }
                    }
                }

            ],function(err, data) {
                return data;
            }) 

    }

    function t2(req, res, next) {
        var test = testFunction();
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a callback from `t2` to `t1`:

```
function t1(callback) {
    db.users.aggregate(
        [{
                $group: {
                    "_id": {
                        "_id": "$_id",
                        "name": "$name",
                        "email": "$email"
                    }
                }
            }

        ], callback) 

}

function t2(req, res, next) {
    t1(function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send("Internal error occurred.")
        }

        return res.status(200).json(data);
    })
})
```